# Reference request: dimension of convex hull of n random points

Tags: reference-request, random-variables, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $X$ be an i.i.d. random sample of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ from a probability distribution that is absolutely continuous with respect to the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Assume $n>d$. I am looking for a textbook reference that shows that the dimension of the convex hull of $X$ is $d$ with probability 1.

Comment: An induction argument on $d$ should work.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. How would you argue that the (d+1)st point cannot lie in the same linear space as the previous points? (Also, I really do need a reference because I want to cite this result)